# SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow Lookup for SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm having issues with my SP Online Workflow. Setting up a custom list for Time-off requests. Person puts in request, task is assigned to their manager, then manager either approves or denies request, then informs the requester of the outcome. That whole part works great.

I've added an option for the requester to cancel the request. If the request has already been approved by the manager then it sends an email to the Manager, HR, & requester saying the request was cancelled. This part works fine.

The part that I'm having issues with is if the request hasn't been approved/rejected by manager and requester cancels. It's not sending out the email to manager and changing the Workflow Status.

I have it configured exactly like the cancel workflow if it's been approved. What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some images of the entire workflow and the Workflow lookup in question:

[Entire Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwnmF.png)

[Workflow Lookup in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ghQ.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think if one of your condition complete, it should just go the next stage in your case which is end of workflow. When you condition is satisfied, you don't need to go through all other `if` anymore.

```
If request cancel equal no
    If outcome equal approved
    Go to next stage
    If outcome equal rejected
    Go to next stage
Else
    If taskStatus equal not started
    Go to next stage
    If taskStatus equal completed
    Go to next stage
```

I switched `not started` and `completed`. Because logically speaking you should go `not started` first.

Comment: So I changed it where taskStatus equal not started was first, but it's still not working properly. Could the reason the "If taskStatus equals completed" works is because at that point before the cancel request is sent with the request being approved the workflow is technically completed, and canceling the request restarts the workflow? Whereas canceling the request before a manager has had an opportunity to approve or deny the request, the workflow is still technically running? If that's the case how would I go about getting around this?

Comment: @RyanBell From the outcomes it seems workflow is still running if you cancel before manager doing anything. The work around will be very different depend on your workflow's logic setting. I would consider add a new "Not started yet" stage. on parallel with your "rejected or approved" stage. Since you are allowing user to cancel the request at anytime.